# Build a jQuery counter with onclick event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was hoping to get pointed in the right direction to start a build I'm attempting. Just getting used to jQuery and not really sure what I'm looking for exactly - hopefully my description below should explain it accurately.

I'm looking to build a slider or counter of sorts, with each slide being two sets of coordinates (ie 22°33'N and 44°55'E) and when the user clicks on a navigation button the coordinates scrolls through to the next set (ie 66°77'N and 88°99'E) perhaps jumbling the numbers as the transition happens.

Now I'm aware this might be a very rudimental question so please excuse my ignorance.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: jquery Cycle2 is very flexible and easy to get going... unless you want to write this your self?

Comment: Not sure if it's the ideal solution for what I'm trying to do. It seems to do text as slides but I want to manipulate the actual text, not it's container.

Comment: Question is not clear. Could you please provide a mock up or test code?

Comment: As I'm struggling to find an example the best I could do was [this](http://aform.lu/index.php?id=3). I imagine something like the numbers scrolling past in the background but triggered by a click event rather than on scroll. Hope this helps, thanks.